# AngularJS1.2 Directive two Way Binding Attribute is not reflected to View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive

I can not use a scope attribute within my view that is obvious available in the scope variable.

Please see the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/aoRU6YDywA0Q25gKpQGz?p=preview

script.js

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('myapp', [
  'myapp.directive',
  'myapp.controller'
]);

angular.module('myapp.controller', []).controller('mylist', function($scope) {
  'use strict';
  $scope.mylist = [{
    name: "peter",
    likes: 10
  }, {
    name: "bob",
    likes: 2
  }];
  $scope.testme = 'fdsds';
});

angular.module('myapp.directive', []).directive('pmTable', function factory() {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    scope: {
      data: '=myvar'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
      // console.log($scope);
    },
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      // Note: The template instance and the link instance may be different objects if the template has been cloned.
      // For this reason it is not safe to do anything other than DOM transformations that apply to all cloned DOM nodes within the compile function.
      // Specifically, DOM listener registration should be done in a linking function rather than in a compile function.

      console.log('inside compile');
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          console.log('preLink');
          console.log(scope);
          console.log(scope.data); // available here
          scope.testme = 'testhere';
          // scope.$apply(); // using that one doesn change anything
        },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          console.log('postLink');
          console.log(scope);
          console.log(scope.data); // available here
          console.log(scope.testme); // available from the parent scope
          // scope.$apply(); // using that one doesn change anything
        }
      };
    }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.3" data-semver="1.2.3" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-controller="mylist">
    {{mylist|json}}
    {{ testme }}
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div pm-table myvar="mylist">
        From parent Scope: {{ testme }} <br />
        {{myvar|json}}<br />
        {{data|json}}<br />
        <!-- this following repeat is not working -->
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in data">
            <td>Name: {{ item.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`pm-table` is an attribute. The scope of the directive is limited to this attribute (or element), since you decided to go with an isolated scope. `console.log(scope.testme);` outputs the value `testhere` which comes from the directive's scope.

`From parent Scope: {{ testme }} <br />` will print `fdsds`, as specified by the controller's scope. The directive does not apply here. The same is true for the `ng-repeat`, of course. `data` is in the directive's scope, which does not apply here.

The simplest solution would be an inherited scope with `scope: true`. Anything else would involve additional work.